# Where to add basic generic data in a symfony application if neither in migrations nor dataFixtures?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In a Symfony application using doctrine it is recommended to build and update the **schema** through `migrations` ([Source](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#container-aware-migrations)).

However to add **fake data** for testing purposes, you are advised to use `DataFixtures` ([Source](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html)).

Now I am wondering, whats the best practice to add basic "static" data, required for the app, being it `Salutation`, `Category`, `Group` and whatnot. Things the app needs in a fresh, clean state.

---

I could not find *any* advice on **where and how to add these kind of generic data**.
The documentation explicitly recommends `migrations` for **schema** and `DataFixtures` for **fake data**:

> [[1](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#container-aware-migrations)] Database migrations are a way to safely update your database **schema** both locally and on production.

> [[2](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html)] Fixtures are used to load a **"fake"** set of **data** into a database that can then be used **for testing** or to help give you some interesting data while you're developing your application.

---

In the past, I added these kinds of data through migrations, through dataFixtures (though could not be processed in a `prod` env) and through console commands. All these works, more ore less, but is there any "best practise" I missed out?

Comment: These are just recommendations. You can still use fixtures to load "real" data but should watch out not to purge the database. You can also just import from a SQL file or write a console command to setup your database.

Comment: The fixtures can't be loaded in a `prod` environment, thus seemed hacky to me. Do you know any best practice / recommendation on this very basic question? The console command approach seems the best so far, to me.

Comment: Sure they can, you just have to enable the bundle for `prod` environment and make sure theyre correctly tagged in prod environment. But just use console command because then its easier to separate dev/text fixure data from prod environments.